# c# listview displaying problems

Tags: c#, file, listview

so i have a listview that displays the filename of the text file thats fine
the problem is foreach textfile i have so say a file is called 8133.txt it has a image file to so 8133.jpg
i want that to match in my listview to the correct textfile

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\OmGRhys Student System Files - 2019\\");
        FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
        foreach (FileInfo f in files)
        {
            foreach (string imageFileName in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg"))
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { f.Name, imageFileName }));
            }
        }
```

[image]

so..

and to keep that pattern for everyfile in the directorys
all textfiles and image files are in the same directory

Comment: You don't want a double loop if those file pairs always match. What is `path` ?

Comment: string path = "C:\\OmGRhys Student System Files - 2019\\";

Comment: i want them to match so if the folder has a 1.txt and a 1.jpg then i want them displayed side by side not habe 1.txt and say 8133.jpg next to it

Comment: If you have that variable you should always use it! - Use just one loop and set the imagename =  f.Name.Replace(".txt", ".jpg"); make sure to test it using File.Exists(imagename ) !!

Comment: i think your not getting what i mean mate                                                                             Column 1:                          Column 2:                                                                                             1.txt                                    1.jpg                                                                                        8133.txt                               8133.jpg                                                                                and so on depending on the files in the folder i want them to match on each column

Comment: http://prntscr.com/pcmfp5  -- check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\OmGRhys Student System Files - 2019\\");
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.txt");

    foreach (FileInfo f in files)
    {
        string imgName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.FullName) + ".jpg";
        string imgFile = Path.Combine(di.FullName, imgName);

        if (File.Exists(imgFile))
            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { f.Name, imgFile }));
    }
```